# How to Remove dates from string in a Dataframe Column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a length shape of (3,7616) I'm trying to clean a certain column shops['full_review_text'] it has values like:

```
' 11/25/2016 1 check-in Love love loved the atmosphere! Every corner of the coffee shop had its own style, and there were swings!!! I ordered the matcha latte, and it was muy fantastico! Ordering and getting my drink were pretty streamlined. I ordered on an iPad, which included all beverage selections that ranged from coffee to wine, desired level of sweetness, and a checkout system. I got my latte within minutes!  I was hoping for a typical heart or feather on my latte, but found myself listing out all the possibilities of what the art may be. Any ideas? ',

 ' 12/2/2016 Listed in Date Night: Austin, Ambiance in Austin BEAUTIFUL!!!! Love the ambiance! Instagram-worthy!!!  Definitely $$$, so be prepared. This is gonna cost you a pretty penny :) Waffle dessert was just decent...nothing to rave about.  But, will probably be back just to be somewhere unique and nice. '

 " 11/30/2016 1 check-in Listed in Brunch Spots I loved the eclectic and homey plush decor and who doesn't want to swing and drink their coffee?  I would categorize this as a pricier coffee place but, to me it was worth it.  After Thanksgiving nobody wants to make brunch so we headed out in search of chicken and waffles.  There is ample parking in the private lot and  ordering is done through I-Pads.  Pick a seat and they will call your name when your items are ready.  Be patient because some of the coffee drinks take longer than others.  I had the cold brew coffee, chicken and waffles and we shared a pop+art!  The po+art was strawberry; light and fluffy on the outside and gooey sweet filling on the inside.  The chicken and waffles wasn't the standard so expect different, complex and interesting flavors from the accompanying slaw and sauce.  I thoroughly enjoyed it but, the waffle was a bit bland and maybe could have used a bit of honey to spruce it up.  The coffee here is spot on and I hear that their hot chocolate is the bomb but, I will have to wait for the weather to cool off to try that.  A great place to be cozy and chat with your friends, a date or read a book. Chicken and waffles Pop tart Coffee See all photos from Carmela S. for The Factory - Cafe With a Soul ",

 ' 11/25/2016 Very cool decor! Good drinks Nice seating  However...  Just about everything is overpriced. $1.50 extra for 3 ounces of Almond Milk in a cortado. No WiFi Music is a bit loud and the mix is odd.  Pleasant French oldies followed by loud techno. Several tables were dirty when we got there. Service is average.  It feels like a Los Angeles coffee shot that is out of place. ',

 ' 12/3/2016 1 check-in They are located within the Northcross mall shopping center facing east toward Burnet Rd with plenty of parking. I loved their computerized user friendly ordering system, it made it easy me to pick & choose all the items I wanted to try. I ordered pop tart, chicken & waffles, strawberry waffles (photos uploaded). This place is ideal for ordering a few dishes to share with your group. Seating is limited since this place is fairly new with lots of visitors. Arrive early and be prepared to wait a bit if you with a large grop. Store front facing Burnet Rd See all photos from Michelle A. for The Factory - Cafe With a Soul ',
```

I'm trying to extract the dates from to put in their own column shops['dates'] and remove them completely from 'full_review_text'.

I've tried:

```
shops['date'] = pd.to_datetime(shops['full_review_text'].str.extract('\((\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\)')[0])

shops['date'] = shops['full_review_text'].str[:11]
```

Neither approaches have helped me due to various reasons such as Nat error and the substring not catching the date right due to format.

Comment: The pattern the pattern looks like dash separated date format `mm-dd-yyyy` but the values in the column seems to be in `mm/dd/yyyy` format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your sample, you can do:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(t['full_review_text'].str.extract(r'^\s*([^\s]+)', expand=False),
                   errors='coerce')

0   2016-11-25
1   2016-12-02
2   2016-11-25
3   2016-12-03
Name: full_review_text, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much I ended up using .replace() to also get the dates out of the full_review_text column. Do you have any good sources to learn RegEx?

Comment: Especially for Python: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#re.match)

```
import re
shops['date'] = pd.to_datetime(shops['full_review_text'].apply(lambda text: re.search('[0-9]{,2}\/[0-9]{,2}\/[0-9]{4}', text)[0]))
```